# get_template_part() Not Working in Loop

Tags: loop, post-formats, get-template-part

I am having trouble getting `get_template_part()` to work on my index.php page. The template part is in the loop and is referencing a 'standard' post format.

**template code:**

```
<section id="content" class="site-content blog-page">

    <div class="container"> 

        <?php if ( is_home() || ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) ) : ?>                 

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'pagination' ); ?>             

            <?php endwhile; ?>            

            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no postes matched your criteria' ); ?></p> 
            <?php endif; ?>        

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- Ends .container -->       

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Url:** http://magneton.carbonium.no/

**EDIT**
Changed the index.php code to reflect @rudtek example. Template parts are still not loading.

Comment: Is there a content.php file in that location?

Comment: @Milo, Yes i have checked and double checked file names and paths. This is very confusing i have used template parts all over this theme but for some reason this is not working. I get no errors, the template-part is simply not adding the additional code.

Comment: Are you sure that it passes the if condition you have get_template_part inside of?

Comment: @Milo, tested that as well http://magneton.carbonium.no/

Comment: maybe I'm not seeing the whole code here so something is missing, but by what I see, you're in a loop asking if a post is home or front page.  This posts aren't home page.  That pull should be out of the loop?

Comment: @rudtek, The template in question is the index.php. Front page is showing the most recent post. There are no static pages set. I am testing is page is either a static blog page or if the page is the most recent posts i.e not static page has been set for the blog.

Comment: Right, but you're doing it in a loop, so you're not asking if index.php is a homepage, you're asking if the post is.  Which it isn't.

Comment: @rudtek, no, `is_home()` references the global `$wp_query` object, not the current post object.

Comment: @rudtek, i have edited the example code as well as responded to your answer.

Comment: Are you using a child theme? If I try to manually enter the URL of your `template-parts` directory in your `magneton` theme directory, I get a 404.

Comment: @Milo, try this, http://magneton.carbonium.no/wp-content/themes/magneton/framework/template-parts/post/

Comment: Then your `get_template_part` path should be `framework/template-parts/post/content`

Comment: Yea this is about as embarrassing as it gets. Why don't you write that as an answer so i can tick it off. You nailed it...and i am left trying to figure how i missed that detail....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about my comment...wouldn't it be simplier to say:

```
<section id="content" class="site-content blog-page">

<div class="container">              
<?php if ( is_home() || ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) ) : ?>  
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h2> There are posts but template parts aren't found </h2>         
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() ); ?>                 
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'pagination' ); ?>  


    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <h2> There are no posts.</h2> 
    <?php endif; ?> 
<?php else : ?>
    <h2> THIS IS not home or front </h2>   
<?php endif; ?> 
</div><!-- Ends .container -->
```

try this, so now we know if it's not home or if it's no posts or if it can't find your templates..

Comment: This may very well be a better structure and i have changed my code to match this example. However the template parts are still not loading their respective code blocks.

Comment: okay now run the code.  it should output an h2 with where there is a problem.

Comment: Added the code it repeats as expected, yet no templat-parts. I am baffled.

Comment: what error did you get back?  1 of the 3 should have showed

Comment: Oh sorry i did not the see the other, i copied the entire code now and the results are three copies of "There are posts but template parts aren't found"

Comment: Okay we know the code is working but your template parts directory is incorrect.  Can you add "framework" as milo suggested?

Comment: I did add it and .....it worked. I am embarrassed and i can't apologize enough for wasting your time. Thank you for trying.

Comment: no worries.  Glad we got it answered.  Could you mark it answered?